# Git/GitHub: How remove deleted files from shown (as deleted) in pull request?

Tags: git, github

I deleted some files, and they show in the Pull Request as deleted(please see the image below)

How can I **NOT** have the files in the Pull Request? (also not as deleted)
[image: Show Deleted files]

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to hide the deleted files from being shown in the GitHub comparer but still having them deleted? Or do you want the deleted files not showing up because they shouldn't be deleted? From what I read you mean the first option, but the accepted answer seems to be answering the second option (or something entirely different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git, *every* commit is a full snapshot of *every file*.

More precisely, every commit holds a full snapshot.  Whatever files are in it, those *are the files*.

There's no such thing as a difference between a commit.  A commit is a single collection of files, plus some metadata.  So asking for the difference between a commit is like asking for the difference between the Statue of Liberty.

Now, we *can* ask about the difference between, say, the Statue of Liberty and the Statue of George Washington in the financial district of NYC.  Or, more sensibly perhaps, we can ask about the difference between the statue of George Washington in the financial district, and the one in Union Square.  But we had to pick *two things* to ask about.  The same is true with commits: we can't ask about the *difference* without picking *two commits*.

That's what a pull request does, though.  When you use GitHub to make a Pull Request—PRs are a GitHub feature, not a Git feature—GitHub picks two commits to compare.  The diff you see is the result of comparing those two commits.  One of the two commits is the *tip commit* of your branch; the other is a commit in what GitHub calls the *base branch*.  (Since Git doesn't have this, we have to do something a bit different in Git, but we can get the same effect there.)

If the PR says that these files are *deleted*, that means:

- The file *does* exist in the base commit.
- The file *does not* exist in the pull-request-branch-tip commit.

If you want the files *not* to be deleted, you must make a new branch-tip commit in which those files *do* exist.  Then they won't be "deleted".  They will instead be in that commit.

Now, once you make some commit, *that commit can never be changed*.  So you can't alter the existing branch-tip commit in your PR.  But you don't *need* to do *that*.  A branch name, in Git, always means *the latest commit on this branch*.  If you add *more* commits, they're now the latest commit(s).  So you can add a new commit to the branch that puts the files back.  Now the branch tip commit has the files.  Or, you can *strip the commit off the branch*.  This is a bit harder: Git is built to *add* commits, not strip them away.  (Stripping them off the tip of a branch doesn't *remove* the commits either: it just makes the branch name locate some *earlier* commit.)

#### All of these alternatives are wrong for your case

You said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835354/git-github-how-remove-deleted-files-from-shown-as-deleted-in-pull-request#comment123444580_69835390) that—and I'm paraphrasing a bit here—these files *should not* be in commits as they are automatically generated.

Now, the fact is, they *are* in some commits.  This fact is unchangeable, because those commits cannot be changed.  You can at most stop *using* those commits, either leaving them in so as not to damage your commit history, or stripping them away so as to make them so hard to find that nobody will use them (damaging the history *on purpose*, in other words).  Leave the files out of the *new* commits.

Any PR will show these as deleted *because they are deleted* by comparison.  That is, a `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` to the *old* commit extracts the files: they are *in* the old commit.  A subsequent `git checkout` or `git switch` to the *newer* commit will then *remove* the files.

Since they're automatically generated, removing them is harmless.  (If it's *not* harmless, they're not properly automatically generated and perhaps they should not be removed.)

Removing the files and committing is probably the right thing to do, and it will show up as a removal, which is also correct.  Just live with that.  Listing the files in `.gitignore` afterwards will help make sure that they don't appear in *future* commits, but does have a minor drawback or two.  You probably won't run into it.

If generating the files automatically is very slow, consider adding some special commits on a special branch that *does* have them, that gets them updated now and then as needed, and allowing people to run `git restore branch -- path/to/generated/files`.  This branch can contain *only* the generated files, since people will use `git restore` to populate their working tree (and not their index / staging-area).

Comment: @torek- thanks for the detailed answer. To make a long story short - this is not possible, right?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "this". Files are either there, or not there. Comparisons tell you the differences between files in commit L (left side) and commit R (right side). You can't have a comparison that says "file is the same" when the file is different or missing: that would be a lie.

Comment: @torek If what you say is true `every commit is a full snapshot of every file`, then if I create a repository with a 1 GB video file and a 1 kB text file, every child commit that only changes the text file would add still add 1 GB to the full size of the repository, even if I would not change the video file. Maybe I understand `snapshot` wrong.

Comment: @Binarian: It would, except that Git cleverly *de-duplicates* identical files. If you change just one byte of that 1GB file, you will see the repository grow quite a bit. Since video files are generally pre-compressed, Git's compression (both up front, and later during object packing) won't help much here either.

Comment: Note that some modern file systems (e.g., ZFS) use this same trick when you make file system snapshots. They mark the original file as "copy on write" (well, ZFS does it that way, but at the block level, not the whole-file level; there are other techniques).

Comment: @torek So snapshot means, every file that is not identical to the parent. Your text implies that the files are *in* the commit, which may be false. But I get your point, commits are not differences to the parent but a mere collection of files or file references of the parent commit.

Comment: Technically, the commit object itself holds only metadata (name, parents, etc.); one of the metadata lines reads `tree <hash>`. It's the `tree` object that represents the snapshot. Tree objects recurse as needed: each one holds (name,mode,hash) tuples where the "name" part is just a component name. The hashes are either further tree hashes or, at terminating points, blob hashes or (for saved gitlink entries) commit hash IDs as found in some other repository.

Comment: The de-duplication happens because the hash ID for the file content is deterministic, based on computing the hash (SHA-1 or SHA-256) of the content bytes. So identical content = identical hash = re-use existing blob; new content = new hash = add new blob to repository DB. Git stores the blobs early, before committing, and relies on `git gc` to clean them out if they wind up unused because of a subsequent `git add` or `git rm` before `git commit`. Running `git commit` runs `git write-tree`, which turns the existing index into trees and reports the top tree hash.

Comment: Note that trees may also get shared: if commit X has `foo/` and `bar/` in it and we modify some file within `foo` but nothing within `bar` and make new commit Y, the top tree for Y will be a new object, and the `foo` sub-tree in the top tree will be a new object, but the `bar` sub-tree is shared across both X and Y.

Comment: If we then `git revert` the commit we just made, we get a new *commit* (with new parent and date-stamps and so on) but we re-use the entire tree from commit X. This makes `git diff` go fast for a lot of cases: it can short-circuit an entire subtree based on tree hash matching.

Comment: In essense—and Linus Torvalds has made this point himself several times—Git is a user-space implementation of a file system with checkpointing features. Commits contain (uncounted, but gc-able) links to the "directories" (trees, which act as a combined dir+inode) and file contents (blobs). The UI is layered atop this file system implementation, but `git hash-object`, `git mktree`, `git write-tree`, and `git commit-tree` expose it if you want to do special tricks. The old `git stash` script, for instance, used this to make its two or three stash commits.

Comment: Just wonder- copying the whole project in the current branch to a new branch, and create a PR to master. Will it help?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't need them as they're automatically generated. they're in .gitignore

If they were previously tracked, your PR records the fact they are no longer tracked (hence the deletion), and ignored (`git check-ignore -v -- a/generated/file` should return an "ignore" rule locally)

In other words, this is expected.

Comment: Do you know a way to override this ?

Comment: @racheliganon No, considering this is what is supposed to be delivered: the record of those files previously recorded, and now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If those files are important for your repository, it would make sense that they are listed in a pull request when they are added, deleted, modified. If you don't want that, it may imply that your files aren't that important, then you can add them to **.gitignore** file.

Comment: I don't need them as they're automatically generated. they're in .gitignore